# no responce from url using python requests for different language

Tags: python, web-crawler, python-requests

I wanted to use Google Translate service to convert a text from one language to another. I know Google Translate is now a paid service and so I didn't use the REST API. I tried the following way just to learn the language and nothing else.

The code is working well when I request a url to translate to language that returns the text in English. For example if you call :-

```
do_trans("Hello World", "fr", "en")
```

**Sample Output**

Bonjour Le Monde

Hello World

The above works well. By working well I mean that when I resent a request to get English text from the French text then the output I get is correct. But if I request a language like Japanese or Chinese (which returns different unicode data) etc. then the translation from Chinese or Japanese to English fails though the first part that is English to other languages works well.

```
# -- coding: utf-8 --

import requests
import re

__base_url = "http://translate.google.com/translate_a/t"
__headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; en) AppleWebKit/420+ (KHTML, like Gecko) "
                  "Version/3.1.2 Safari/525.21"
}
params = {
    "client": "t",
    "ie": "UTF-8",
    "oe": "UTF-8",
    "sl": "en",
    "tl": "ja",
    "text": "こんにちはモンキー！"
}
matcher = re.compile(r'\[\[\["(.*?)","(.*)","(.*)",""\]\]')


def do_trans(text, tolang, fromlang):
    params['sl'] = fromlang
    params['tl'] = tolang
    params['text'] = text

    req = requests.get(__base_url, params=params, headers=__headers)
    if req.status_code == 200:
        transtext = re.search(matcher, req.text)
        if transtext:
            return transtext.group(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    t1 = do_trans("Hello World", "zh-CN", "en")
    print(t1)
    t2 = do_trans(t1, "en", "zh-CN")
    print t2
```

**Sample output for above :-**

你好世界

None

Any help and info on how to solve this error or problem would be nice.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the problem is with your matcher expression, you see, if you printed the req.text you would note that when you translate from en to zh-CN you get:

```
[[["你好世界","Hello World","Nǐ hǎo shìjiè",""]],,...
```

Which matches your expression of `[[["something", "something", "something", ""]]`.

When you translate back to English from Chinese you get:

```
[[["Hello World","你好世界","","Nǐ hǎo shìjiè"]],,...
```

Which doesn't match because you don't have an empty `""` in the fourth item on the list.

Fix your matcher to:

```
# Note that I've added (.*) to the fourth item in the list
matcher = re.compile(r'\[\[\["(.*?)","(.*)","(.*)","(.*)"\]\]')
```

And you'll get:

> 你好世界
>
> Hello World

PS:

About the `UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 38-41: character maps to <undefined>`, is basically saying: "I can't transform what you pass into the charmap (cmd coding) codec.". Fix it by passing a utf-8 string.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    t1 = do_trans("Hello World", "zh-CN", "en")
    print(t1.encode('utf-8'))
    t2 = do_trans(t1, "en", "zh-CN")
    print(t2.encode('utf-8'))
```

Although that will print something, I couldn't make cmd output the chinese string correctly, there is still VERY limited support for unicode in the CMD shell.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Thats works. There's another error I encountered and that is the following :-

    UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in    position 38-41: character maps to <undefined>

I get this when I run it in windows cmd but on linux it works properly.

Comment: Thanks. I even tried what you have done but I still get the erros though. I even used locale lib and used it this way

    t2.encode(locale.getprefferedencoding())

something like this but didn't worked.